# c# is there a way to stop a foreach loop until the event occurs again?

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

I am currently trying to program a foreach loop and I am coding it into my button click event. The problem I have is that the loop just goes straight through to the end of the array, what I want it to do is stop at each string in the array until the button is clicked again and then it will move onto the next string. Should I use break; or continue;?

```
foreach (string s in weapons)
{
    pictureBox9.Image = Image.FromFile(s + ".png");
    counter++;
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Since you saving a counter why not simply take the element at the counter index? Without looping.

Comment: You want to change the image every time is button is pressed, do you?

Comment: be careful not to block your ui-thread

Comment: Just stop using `foreach`. If you need one image to be shown after button is clicked, then just run this code once. You can utilize `IEnumerable` to yield one "weapon" at time, or just simply store an arrya and a counter, just like you almost do in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Stop using a `foreach` loop because it will freeze your UI when you stop/pause the loop.

Use something like this instead.

```
counter++;
if(counter >= weapons.Count)
{
    counter = 0;
}
string weapon = weapons[counter];
pictureBox9.Image = Image.FromFile(weapon + ".png");
```

You alread have a counter. Increment it if the button is pressed and if it get's to high reset it. Then you can select the image from your list and at least you update your image.

A good improvement would be to load all images at the start and put them in a list to replace the `weapons` list. You could access the item in the list via the `counter` as well.

Comment: Almost there, I'd just recommend not to do File I/O on the GUI Thread. Maybe the images should be preloaded or something.

Comment: @Fildor Loading all images is not always feasible, best is to go for the Async version, that way Ui thread never blocked, while image is loaded

Comment: Yes, freezing the UI is always a problem. But if you store the images in a list instead of loading it each time it should be ok. I never had any issues changing images in WPF apps for example.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom what you are saying will work for WPF, but not for Web Apps / Javascript, that's why Async will be a better option, even initial image loading / caching that also shall be done Asynchronously